# My event listener doesn't work from my reusable bundle in Symfony 4.1

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

Short story : I have some diffulties to use a listener properly on my custom "vendor" bundle.

I'm coding a reusable bundle for Symfony 4.1 framework (for managing Users). I put the whole bundle in this location of a new symfony project : myproject/lib/AcmeUserBundle/src/

Just like this [Demo](https://codeburst.io/5-tips-for-developing-symfony-reusable-bundles-2276480e99a4)

Because my bundle is at a non usual place, I changed my config/services.yaml like this (in case this is relevent) :

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true
        public: false      

    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    Acme\UserBundle\:
        resource: '../lib/AcmeUserBundle/src/*'
        exclude: '../lib/AcmeUserBundle/src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests}'

    Acme\UserBundle\Controller\:
        resource: '../lib/AcmeUserBundle/src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```

Then, I coded a login form (that you don't care much), and when a user logged in, I want to update his last datetime connexion info in database. So I have built a listener following this [tutorial](https://rihards.com/2018/symfony-login-event-listener/) on the `security.interactive_login` event :

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\EventListener;

use DateTime;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

class LoginListener
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * LoginListener constructor.
     *
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param InteractiveLoginEvent $event
     */
    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        // Get the User entity.
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        /** @var \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User $user */
        $user->setLastLoggedAt(new DateTime());
        $this->entityManager->persist($user);
        $this->entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

***lib/AcmeUserBundle/src/Resources/config/services.yaml*** looks like :

```
services:
    Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\LoginListener:
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login }
```

***lib/AcmeUserBundle/src/DependencyInjection/AcmeUserExtension.php*** looks like :

```
class AcmeUserExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * @param array            $configs
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $loader = new YamlFileLoader(
            $container,
            new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config')
        );
        $loader->load('services.yaml');
    }
}
```

I can see my service using these symfony commands :
`php bin/console debug:autowiring`
`php bin/console debug:container`
But I can't see anything with :
`php bin/console debug:event-dispatcher`

When I log-in with my user, no error occurs, and of course, no date is inserted in database. That's why I think my listener is not properly registered.

Any idea why ?

### EDIT after Cerad's comment :

Output of `php bin/console debug:container LoginListener`

```
 ---------------- ------------------------------------------------
  Option           Value
 ---------------- ------------------------------------------------
  Service ID       Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
  Class            Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
  Tags             -
  Public           no
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             no
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        yes
  Autoconfigured   yes
 ---------------- ------------------------------------------------
```

We can see that the ***Tags*** part is empty. That's the reason why my listener is ignored.
And... it works if I comment that part of my ***config/service.yaml*** :

```
...
    #Acme\UserBundle\:
    #    resource: '../lib/AcmeUserBundle/src/*'
    #    exclude: '../lib/AcmeUserBundle/src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests}'
...
```

New output of `php bin/console debug:container LoginListener`

```
 ---------------- -----------------------------------------------------------
  Option           Value
 ---------------- -----------------------------------------------------------
  Service ID       Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
  Class            Acme\UserBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
  Tags             kernel.event_listener (event: security.interactive_login)
  Public           no
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             no
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        no
  Autoconfigured   no
 ---------------- -----------------------------------------------------------
```

***Tags*** is now correct and my listener works properly

Comment: Have you verified that AcmeUserExtension::load() is being called?  Trying to use autowire on an external bundle is unusual but it should work.  And of course you do have an AcmeUserBundle class defined and being called in app/bundles.php..

Comment: AcmeUserExtension::load() is being called for sure because I can see my service while using symfony command : *php bin/console debug:container* (And I tried a beautiful die("boom") that confirm that as well).
And yes, my bundle is defined in *config/bundles.php*

Comment: For some reason autowire is interfering with the tagging process.  Not sure why.  exclude your login listener and all should be well.  I guess it is one reason why you don't normally autowire external bundles.  You will have to manually inject the entity manager.

Comment: Thx @Cerad, I add an edit after your comment. It helped a lot. My service definition in config/service.yaml was interfering with my service.yaml from my custom bundle. It also worked if I do exclude the **EventListener** directory in config/service.yaml : `exclude: '../lib/AcmeUserBundle/src/{DependencyInjection,EventListener,Entity,Migrations,Tests}'`. Do you have any info why it interfers that way ? Anyway, if you want, you can add an official answer and I'll accept it. Or I can make it by myself later.

Comment: I think I will just delete all my **Acme\UserBundle\*** service config from `config/service.yaml`, and manually define all my services inside my external bundle. It seems to be a better practice.

Comment: I think it is because autowire really only knows about its own services file.  It does not know about your bundles service definition so it ends up overwriting it.  And yes I fully agree with removing your Acme stuff from the app's file.  I don't really want to write an answer because I'm just guessing at the behavior.  So feel free to post your own.